# i want to change my sdk path in android adt?

Tags: android, eclipse

a few days ago i have lost my R.java file from my android app app project from android adt while cleaning it...as it was showing some errors when i was trying to add the feature of ads in my xml file...now i am unable to recover my R.java file in the project .

I have tried many options such as:-

1. cleaning the project .
2. checking for errors in the xml file and corrected and tried to clean the project once again.
3. copied and pasted the res,gen and android manifest.xml file in the new project of the same in another workspace and pasting the new R.java file generated over there into the actual workspace but still its not working and showing errors.
4. i tried to cut and paste the sdkmanager.exe from the actual folder to some folder elsewhere and tried to clean the project again to regain its R.java file but it is still not working and the sdk manager is showing the same path even though i have shifted it somewhere else...

now what am i supposed to do...

Comment: and how to download new sdk for an adt which i already have but its sdk is missing....

Answer (score 1):

To change SDK path: Window/Preferences/Android.. and then Set SDK Location

Answer (score 1):

R.java is an auto generated file and it's error is based on errors in Manifest file or resources , maybe there is an unnamed string in your string file ,if you can, post your R.java file errors. and for changing sdk path its through `Window -> Preferences - > Android` .

Answer (score 0):

1. On Windows : Window > Preferences > Android. Then click on "Browse" to change SDK path.
2. On Mac : ADT > Preferences > Android and "Browse"

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide your R.java file errors mine was R cannot be resolved to a variable and I had to go to `project properties -> java build path`, then make sure your libraries are selected and clean and build and if that doesn't work delete your bin and gen folder and clean and build...Hope this works for you good luck!

Comment: mine was the same too...R cannot be resolved to a variable as my R.java file was missing from the gen folder...

Comment: i somehow managed to recover my R.java file by changing some of my xml files but it is still showing the  error like following xml file cannot be resolved ...in the findViewById(R.layout.bcb); it is the same xml file where i wanted to display the ads by using admobs key as instructed in the developers.android.com.....